# MySQL Import data from CSV: replace ALL blank values with \N

Tags: mysql, csv

I am loading some CSV data into MySQL and have various csv files all coming in through the one Load Data Infile call going to different tables. I want to not have to \N all empty cells before import for MySQL to accept it.

I can see that you can set particular columns to null [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410876/mysql-load-data-infile-na-to-null-transformation). I want this to automate the whole CSV file without specifying particular columns as data coming in is dynamic. I can't seem to find a bulk/dynamic way of doing this.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: What about inserting the data like it is, and then update all empty strings to NULLs?

Comment: Thanks Paul. Many of the data fields are int, etc so MySQL straight up rejects the import.